# php array from many to many database

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having trouble regarding having a record with only one line instead of several records
I have an issue with the following:
A user choose a place, and that place can have several subplaces each one with an id, so i have one main table, another one with places and other many to many.
When i use a select (pdo) gives me an array, the problem is since the user choose for example 5 places, a i have five records and i would like to have only one.
This how i'm doing but no success

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $visitas_dominios = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $idVisita = $row['idVisita'];
        foreach ($visitas_dominios as $idVisita => $reservation) {
            $json[]=$reservation;
        }
        echo json_encode($json);
```

So but this code you can see i must have 2 arrays to join "Turma" and "Descricao". When i use this code i have wrong records. Instead of having 4 "Turmas" i have something like this

```
2ºB,1ºA,1ºA,1ºB,2ºA,2ºA,
```

And it's easy to see they repeated...

Any help?

UPDATE

And the query

```
SELECT v.idVisita, e.Escola, d.Departamento, dom.Descricao, p.Nome, t.Turma, v.Destino, v.StartDate, vt.numAlunos, v.TotalAluno,v.PdfVisita, v.Avaliacao
                                    FROM
                                        visitas AS v
                                        ");
```

Comment: I think the query is the important part here. Can you add the query to your question? And a small example of the table structure.

Comment: check update please